# Sophos for Ubuntu blocking Flatpak application installs

Tags: antivirus, whitelist, flatpak, ubuntu-19.10

I have installed Sophos for Ubuntu and it has been working fairly well until I decided to try Flatpak.

When installing or updating anything using Flatpak, I now get this pop up:

[error popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhUBm.png)

with this corresponding error on the terminal:

```
    ********************** Sophos Anti-Virus Alert *****************
    Error scanning file
    "/var/tmp/flatpak-cache-6TPQJ0/org.freedesktop.Platform.Locale- 

     37ALJ0/repo-WTmN4b-lock".
     Access to the file has been denied
```

Searching the Google webs didn't really give me anything except this note on Github
https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/issues/3512

Any suggestions to how to whitelist or otherwise ignore these files?

```
    $ flatpak --version
    Flatpak 1.4.3

    NAME="Ubuntu"
    VERSION="19.10 (Eoan Ermine)"
    ID=ubuntu
    VERSION_ID="19.10"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The savlog or syslog might give more information about what error SAV is hitting trying to scan the files.

```
/opt/sophos-av/bin/savlog -100

tail /var/log/syslog
```

It's likely that the files will need to be excluded, which you can using savconfig

```
/opt/sophos-av/bin/savconfig exclude /var/tmp/flatpak-cache-*
```

Comment: The logs simply repeated the same error message several times.  So I went ahead and used the savconfig exclude above and installed VLC as a test.

no errors this time.

Thank you!